# SSL Certificate for multiple domains

Tags: ssl

I bought SSL certificate from a trusted CA for my website.Now it is going to be multi tenent.
so my question is -
can I use same certificate for all my new domains or i'll have to buy another certificate.
can any one suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your certificate.
If it contains all your domains in the subject alternative names section you can use it for all these domain, if not you can't.

Comment: it means i need to buy a new wildcard certificate or multidomain certificate ?

Comment: Wildcards do not help if you have multiple domains, e.g. there is no wildcard like `www.*.com`, only `*.domain.com`. But you can have certificates which include `*.dom1.com`,`dom1.com`,`*.dom2.com` etc all inside a single certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to buy wild card SSL for your multi tenant, If you use subdomain for your customers. Else, single domain SSL is enough

Answer (score 0):

1. If this is a multidomain SSL, it will be imported to the server and you may add more sites till tenants permitted.
   OR
2. If the SSL is single domain, and you want to reuse for a different domain and not the original domain, then create a fresh CRS and apply for a rekey. you'll be able to change the domain from www.test.com to www.test2.com.
   **remember, once you've rekeyed for the new domain, the www.test.com will not be under SSL.**